# Access 2013 web app - Import CSV data

Tags: sharepoint-2013, ms-access-2013

I am creating an Access 2013 web app and would like to be able to regularly load data from a csv file into an existing table. In a normal Access db this is very straight forward however I cannot find any programmatic way to do it for a web app... Pretty new to this so any help would be greatly appreciated.